# Tikz local style within subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, tikz-styles

I've many "tikzpicture"s which are part of a "subfigure" environment. I don't want to use a global "\tikzstyle". I can write them in each of the "tikzpicture"s. This creates time, space, and editing issues.

Can I easily create local \tikzstyle that is only part of a subfigure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. you can do this on two ways:

- use `\tikzset` (not `tikzstyle`, it is deprecated) and put them after `\begin{tikzpicture}`, for example

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
      every node/.style = {draw, align= center, ...},
           arrow/.style = {thick,-{Latext[]} }
      ...
          }
  \node (first) {...};
  ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```
- include styles as `tikzpicture` options, for example:

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style = {draw, align= center, ...},
           arrow/.style = {thick,-{Latext[]} }
      ...
  ]
  \node (first) {...};
  ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```

Is this what you asking for? Apparently not (according to your comment) , so ...

**Upgrade:** In the case, that you like to have common `\tikzse{...}` for a figure with number of sub figures, than put it after `\begin{table˙, something like this:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
 \tikzset{
 every node/.style = {draw, align= center, ...},
      arrow/.style = {thick,-{Latext[]} }
        ...
            }
    \begin{subfigure}{<width>}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (first) {...};
    ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{subfigure}
    ... more subfigures ...
    \caption{...}\label{...}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: In subfigure, I had to write them into every tikzpicture. I'm looking something like a local definition for the subfigure. Or should I say, for every chapter, section etc. define local styles

Comment: My answer exactly do this. If you have in the mind something else, you should ask more clear, what you like to obtain. Now I guesing, that you like to have `\tikzest` "locally" for all sub figures in figure. If this is a case, than put ``tikzset` after `\begin{figure}`.

Comment: That is what actually I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Zarko The pgfmanual states that "All TikZ commands should be given inside this environment, except for the \tikzset command" (in page 128 of the manual). Any ideas why this one should not add `tikzset` inside a `tikzpicture` environment?

Comment: @adosar, you misunderstand/interpret  this sentence. You cannot use `tikz` commands (like `\draw`, `\fill`,  `path`, etc,) outside of `tikzpicture` environment, Exception is only  `\tikzset` command, which can be used also outside of it (for example in document preamble or in figure environment before `tikzpicture` as is case in the my answer).

Comment: @Zarko Oops, you are correct. That happens when you read the manual after midnight :). +1 for the elegant answer in the OP!